# How to call an "id" from the "actionLayout"

Tags: java, android

I have this in the `menu.xml`:

```
<menu>
<item
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/add"
    ...
/>
</menu>
```

and in the add layout we have this item:

```
<LinearLayout>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/title"
    ... 
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

and I want to assign an actionListener to the EditText item, so which I have these two options to call the item with the "title" id. what is the difference between these two references:

```
// method #one:
// call it from its parent, "add"
EditText edit = (EditText) menu.findItem(R.id.add).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.title);

// method #two: 
// call it directly 
EditText edit2 = (EditText) menu.findItem(R.id.title);
```

Please note that Extra codes are removed